# Dependent visa for unmarried partner EU/Canada

Tags: canada, uk-visa, spain, dependent-visa, europe

I am looking to relocate to Europe (preferably Spain/Germany) or Canada, visa sponsorship for me shouldn't be an issue as my company has offices in all these locations. But I am worried about my partner who might require a dependent visa which entitles her to work. I read that UK does support visa for unmarried couples but is there similar policy with the above mentioned countries?

Also, can we both apply together for the visa, or for instance if we want to relocate to uk, I need to be in UK for X time for her to start her visa process.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your citizenship?  What is your partner's citizenship?

Comment: both of us are Indian

Comment: @fireants For the UK see https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/869768/SWS_Dependant_Guidance_02-2020.pdf

Comment: @Traveller thanks for the doc, although I am still confused if I need to stay in UK before them to apply or both can apply together.